# What am I missing in this proof with uniform boundedness principle

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

I have the following exercise:  Suppose $y=\left(y_{j}\right)_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of complex numbers. Prove that if the series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} y_{j} \bar{x}_{j}$ is convergent for any sequence $x=\left(x_{j}\right)_{j=1}^{\infty} \in c_{0}$ then $y \in \ell_{1}.$

My attempt: Consider the following:
\begin{align*}
        T_n(x) : & c_0  \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}  \\
         & x\longmapsto \sum_{j=1}^{n} \bar{x}_j y_j 
         \end{align*}
Note that, due to the hypotesis, $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left|\left| T_n(x) \right|\right|= \left|\left| \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \bar{x}_j y_j \right|\right| < \infty$. Now we can apply the uniform boundedness principle, that tells us that $\sup \nolimits _{{n\in \mathbb{N},\|x\|=1}}\|T(x)\|= \sup \nolimits _{n \in \mathbb{N}}\|T_n\|<\infty$.

In this part is where I am confused, because $\sup \nolimits _{{n\in \mathbb{N},\|x\|=1}}\|T(x)\| =\left|\left| \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \bar{x}_j y_j\right|\right|\leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\bar{x}_j y_j|\leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |y_j|$. This last sum is what we want to be finite in order to see that $y\in \ell_1$, but how can I finish this argument?

Comment: Show that $||T_n||=\sum_{j=1}^n|y_j|$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich But, is that true? the inequality is obvious, but the other isn't necessarily true, or am I missing something?

Comment: "Is that true?" is a curious question - why would I have suggested this if I didn't think it was true?

Comment: Oh, ok sorry, I am new in bounding operators, i though that I needed to prove an inequality for the sums, I wasn't thinking on the operator. Thanks

Comment: Hint: For every $z\in\Bbb C$ there exists $\alpha\in\Bbb C$ with $|\alpha|=1$ and $\alpha z=|z|$.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have it using a sucession $a_n=(\frac{y_1}{|y_1|},...,\frac{y_n}{|y_n|},0...)$.

Comment: Right. Except exactly that formula doesn't work if $y_j=0$. Doesn't matter, if $y_j=0$ let $a_j=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides observing that $T_n$ is continuous for obvious reasons,  there is no need to compute its norm.   Once the
hypothesis guarantees  that
$$
  T(x):= \lim_{n\mapsto \infty } T_n(x)
  $$
exists for every $x$, a well known Corollary of the Uniform Boundedness Principle, known as the Banach-Steinhauss
Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Corollaries), implies that $T$ is continuous.

Since we know that $c_0' =\ell^1$, it follows that there exists some $z = (z_j)_{j=1}^\infty $ in $\ell^1$, such that
$$
  T(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_jz_j,
  $$
for all $x$.
By computing both sides on  the standard basis vectors of $c_0$,  one easily deduces that $y_j=z_j$,  from where it follows
that $y$ lies in $\ell^1$.